# Python: Finding the longest sentence in file

Tags: python

I have a file (a book actually) in .txt.
I have to find the longest sentence in this file.

I tried:

```py
print(max(open('file.txt', 'r'), key=len))
```

but it gives me only the longest line.

Not sure how I should do that properly. Any advices?

Comment: what exactly is your desired output?

Comment: How do you define "sentence"? Is it any string ending with a period? What about question mark or exclamation mark? How are you going to differentiate a period ending a sentence from a period in an abbreviation, like `M.Sc.`? Without answers to those questions answer is impossible.

Comment: you will have to go line by line and figure our where a sentence ends. i dont know the structure of you file but you may want to consider that some sentences span more than one line

Comment: Firstly, you should  remember to `close` anything you `open`. You could read the entire file into memory (with `read`) and then split the value by `.`, but as Blotosmetek said, it can be quite hard to properly split sentences due to abbreviations and other punctuation.

Comment: Well, my task is to analyze some book with regard to sentence length, paragraph lenghts, vocabulary etc to see what is the quality of the author of this book.

I know that some dots can be snaky, so I'm just wondering how can I distinguish them.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably solve this using an off the shelf solution like NLTK.

NLTK has a sentence tokenizer that will render you text into sentences, accounting for variations like ! and ?, while also avoiding false positives like "etc."

For example:

```
import nltk

text = "this is a sentence. this is also a sentence. this is too."
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
print(max(sentences, key=len))
# prints 'this is also a sentence.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is basic. You are separating sentences by full-stop.

```
sentence = "study well for your future. study well for you. study well."
sentence_list = sentence.split(".")
length_of_sentence = [len(i) for i in sentence_list]
print(sentence_list[length_of_sentence.index(max(length_of_sentence))])
```